# How to add my own jekyll theme to GitHub pages?

Tags: github, web, themes, jekyll, github-pages

I've downloaded a jekyll theme from:
http://jekyllthemes.org/

But it seems git hub doesn't have the theme in theme chooser.

How I can add my own theme?
I've already done the website locally, but finally github doesn't support the theme, which is upsetting.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the theme gem, copy all the files directly to your Jekyll instance, respecting theme directories, then remove any reference to the theme in `_config.yml`.

Upload the Jekyll website including the theme files and Github pages should be able to show the right design.

Comment: @JoostS There is something broken in there, the intention is good but implementation doesn't convince me. The only case I find it useful the way the are now is to set up a website in 5 minutes.

Comment: I totally agree. Jekyll was better without the gem themes. People are having a hard time understanding how it works, which makes Jekyll as a whole less attractive for newcomers.